# how are variables from main scope treated inside a python multiprocess func?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

It's a bit of a dummy question but here it is:

the following piece of code runs fine:

```
from sklearn import datasets
import multiprocessing

iris = datasets.load_iris()

def parse(x):
    # do something with iris and x
    print(len(iris['data']),x)
    return x

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
    results = pool.starmap(parse, [(1,),(2,),(3,)])
```

Is variable "iris" copied inside each process scope ?

This is not clear for me because I don't pass it directly to "parse" function

Comment: Yes, it works, but you should build an main function and create iris there, then pass it to functions

Answer (score 0):

I guess variables from main scope are copied inside each process if are used there. "top" command in linux, indicates the same amount of memory in both processes:
[image]